# How to measure a dc or ac signal using PC as oscilloscope?

Tags: oscilloscope, microphone, sound

I want to measure for ex a battery 0.7V dc using a program like Visual Analyser/Soundtrack Oscilloscope/jDTF/Scope/xoscope. I connect the negative pole of the battery to sleeve and the pozitive to ring 
[image]

But I dont see any changes on soundtrack oscilloscope. I tested it with microphone on the same plug in and it was respondign to my voice, but when I plug in the dc voltage nothing is changed, there is only noise. Do you know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Audio is AC, dc is blocked. You need to ac couple the signal. Have you looked up the recommended circuits for that software?

Comment: PC mic inputs are often on stereo sockets, so you have and, left and right. Secondly, the mic input my well be AC coupled, so you won't see any signal from DC source. Thirdly 0.7V is too high for mic level, but OK for line level input ( also usually stereo and AC coupled).

Comment: I know the max volt is 5V to not damage the audio card

Comment: I think left=chanel 1 and right=chanel 2 as oscilloscope, and the ground as com, correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Do you understand the previous comments? There is a series capacitor on the input to your soundcard. You can not measure DC.

Comment: Yes I understand that. There is not capacitor but many rezistor pot and fuse. I can measure DC with multimeter. I find oscilloscope more usefull for non DC signals, but I i have not tested it yet. I have not frequency generator to test it.

Comment: So you need a signal to test it? You can use the headphone output of an mp3 player or radio of phone etc as a signal source.

Comment: What everyone is telling you is that there IS a capacitor inside the PC. You will not be able to measure DC on the PC audio channels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are differences, you can't get DC into a sound card as everybody is telling you. Hopefully you can see the differences here. 
Oscilloscope probes also have a much better bandwidth than a 3.5mm cable. The oscilloscope also has an "amplifier" to gain the signal.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH8OUH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>